# MongoAlchemy regex return nothing

Tags: python, regex, mongodb, mongoalchemy

I'm testing MongoAlchemy for a project and I've to search user by name.

I'm trying to make a regex but query result is always empty.

I tried two methods :

```
import re
users = User.query.filter({"name":re.compile("/a/", re.IGNORECASE)}).all()
```

And :

```
users = User.query.filter(User.name.regex('/a/', ignore_case=True)).all()
```

Even if I use a very general regex like **/.*/**, the result is always empty.

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe because you should be using `a` instead of `/a/`? You are using Python patterns, and regex delimiters are never part of Python regexps.

Comment: Yeah.  Strip those slashes which in other contexts (Perl, sed or whatever) may mean "search".  Here you just have to give the regexp itself.  Calling it with `filter` states that a search is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) are not defined using `/regexp/`, this is javascript syntax.

The proper way to initialize regular expressions would be:

```
re.compile(r".*", re.IGNORECASE)
```

So you should use:

```
users = User.query.filter({"name": re.compile(r".*", re.IGNORECASE)}).all()
```